# Can't run project in Eclipse on existing Apache Tomcat server

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, server

I've downloaded and configured apache tomcat 10.1 in eclipse and even started the server successfully, but when i want to start a project and click on "Run As" and then "Run On Server", apache is not showing up as an option and i can't even pick "Choose An Existing Server". Anybody can help?["Run On Server" window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShDAk.png)

I've tried changing the port numbers, the configuration path, none of them helped and i also tried changing the project facets in the project properties. Here i see some people picked "Dynamic Web Module", but that option doesn't show up for me.[Project Facets options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMJox.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what Composer is, but a project can be either a Dynamic Web Project or a Static Web Project, not both. Apache Tomcat can only be used to launch Dynamic projects.  The "WST Server Adapters" feature contains a Preview server that can serve projects with the Static Web facet, as well as (I think, haven't tried it) some support for Apache httpd.